# Delegate with generic type only known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

In my code I have declared an interface as follows:

```
interface IGeneric
{
    T GetOfType<T>();
}
```

And I want to invoke the interface's method with a generic type only known at runtime. This is how I do it currently, and it works:

```
Type genericArgument = ...
object interfaceImplementation = ...

MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(IGeneric).GetMethod("GetOfType").MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
methodInfo.Invoke(interfaceImplementation, null);
```

but because I have to call this part of code quite often, I would like to cache the method info in a delegate. I tried this delegate definition

```
private delegate T GetOfTypeDelegate<T>();
```

and tried to create a delegate using the method info I retrieved like shown above like this:

```
GetOfTypeDelegate<?> deleg = (GetOfTypeDelegate<?>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetOfTypeDelegate<?>), methodInfo);
```

but since I **don't know the type of the generic argument at compile time**, I don't know what to put where I used the `?` or how to make this work at all.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Is this your own interface? Since you'll be calling the method non-generically anyhow, I'd think in terms of rewriting the interface to provide a non-generic version of the method that just returns `object`. "Type known only at runtime" really isn't a good use case for a generic method, for reasons you've discovered.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you, you're right. I will resort to rewriting the interface if there is no other way. Currently, I'd rather not want to do that, because too much other code relies on that generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise having generic and non-generic versions of the method, much like `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` while also explicitly implementing `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

"Type known only at runtime" is exactly what generics aren't intended to be used for. The way you're calling this method, you only ever get `object` out of it anyway. Better to have a real ordinary non-generic method that just returns `object`.

```
   T GetOfType<T>();
   object GetOfType(Type t);
```

You don't even need to worry about overload resolution. There's some extra burden placed on the class implementing the interface, admittedly. But as you've seen, there's going to be a burden somewhere.

Comment: I'm going to try and see if your solution works for me and if it does, I will accept this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: That did the trick for me, thank you very much. Also, the burden is nothing compared to the performance overhead I had when not using the delegate. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Awesome.